# Generate webhook signature using client_secret for Oauth 2.0 application

Tags: database, security, hash, oauth-2.0, secret-key

I'm currently developing a SAAS that allow 3rd party application to connect.

On 3rd party app creation, I generate client_id and client_secret. I save a hashed version of client_secret in the database.

Based on user actions, I need to send events to webhook url as well and need to use a HMAC signature.

2 questions:

1. How to properly save the client_secret inside my DB in order to be secure BUT ALSO allow to display that secret as plain text inside the SAAS?
2. As the client_secret is hashed inside the DB, how to create the webhook signature and allow the 3rd party app to validate it?

Thanks